# Animating content in a temperature chart using Ractive

Tags: javascript, animation, ractivejs

I'm playing with animation in Ractive, but failing miserably!

I'm building a simple temperature chart which you can see running [here](https://ractive.js.org/playground/#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-GQVzQCBIjoAUgOALJ0bcbjd0ADKAHkAHIAEXd8q548V5BHlYuZmbYFWy9XTjtr7PLUw7Y7Xth3LNQxwnAsp25DFgDkHEwApbpnmLSc3EWFAUJoKlvG0OQ-ACIIaBAAgMHgBg9hITJsiYEhjBIBwAHcSAAJThKi0EdYBsNiCIojQSpTExSVeNMPAuNXfjMSsGw7EjESuJ-P9SRIVsSFMDcRNUgcNNMbdtLobTdJBNTtPUoz9KMo9tJPbSz20i8TQ7USPDIBtMFtLivBAZpWjCSowgAYUscQ1F2dg1BBC80DUYQ9gTMInIKTzXwwXzlI8jFeXAcVUoAZgAdg9BKfHRYBMpdXKADZCvSshSrCcqoBIAAWKhqucqk6qyvhUqagBONrEoy+rssaiqAAYBuKoaurAVKKqq-AaqqMqRsqCr+sW9qSpW7rRo2oqeU6hq1tazbBtqnbZsagBWHLJsOy6eqa+6Osexqco29KOy4-BeXanRUCQdz2p6PwkHNSpwUkNQAWsdcSDItd3U4rbXhkGVPDugAqEht1QMAGiQK4MEdBHwZIV1vXSjp2pp9QcEprxEPUSickJtRuBi9BSdMF0NNcglku7cUQVKnRpDKCoSGusbZZBWFDTUVh+IVtAAEk1BPSRHg9CnvSIkBzHgAABSEbFWcE4Q4FHbzNlALZabgEDifjWSuSwUChNBWEkZAoyp54MBgcxKmkBBHVMBoGjkO25CYyx3c91YmO933bnotArjthp6MscFwVMd1IRgLmI9z-PC4D22kVWDPrUqNQoRihAq+OO3VhjCG6Kb8HW7pjQPDAFBhDXG3jitPgbRIKhZYYMA+66dR3Z0OIqi49vLeEJ2XYohOPa9n2-ZBDAKwwDvmG4cFW7IdvDQALz4kgxoaAAOPLrpkYRr71JAdD0JXKhfE-q3HoE8h6VBnmNAApCAlA5Y-72GVtPEQsCYowFYPYSoY1YHuxSB3bgd9EGVHdjAHQzBVi4IXszNQgk9jsGCGPUBaB67T1ljA7w-dvANBYHoSwzJWTsjXs8fUhpshSyJhgDM2s0CwICJPCBKC5ie1EFgho11FEeE4R4bssIyHQkYXAg0RpxHEykegWByisGwPokYZEEC2FUK5NosM9x9hCNvCI4xahsyrjKEwaxtiwD2OgbAsBU9IHsOEb-f+SCJoTRyiIJ+ODLB4PvkQkgJC9EUJSY4ge6hCSLnfETVc7jjiJ09sISoqwqAaOrube+j9n4VWARwxeagGhhmTIIgxnixHeIor4tioTmHyNYSEuY4JMyoEqOacEKALFoDSKscGvB+nmCilqWB8CYmqI-rUzwPQbE6DsSQL4DQcoXMuZE+mbSOkamkfouYvTASVAkWYmRcwjknIiVs6J6SJpUC9Mk1JBD0mZPIZQ1p1CGjPOogY8plhKmnPGZo25sKOB3KZBGZgpSejgqZDw7gkglJfC9KcslcTkmkPIbM8JZLJEICMCQTElyqVZLkeA6e9KMxMpZRctl5DLFcpSL8HlOhmWsrmAipF2CoVOPyei34IFcUoCFc-F++yejtzrqM92CBcxyrye0nsj4VVCtWOqlpqLoVhmxY89qzypYyCiDkb+XygnNWukCriYTgnXLUFo-JkpJjTAwKUsgjr+nOr8R89q7q-Xf19WM-1Ea-kAOnns4QT9s2yutfK9pLjdhuNNWPCNRi+mvNMQgaRbrAkJq4rSqx68a4NIgQ0IB+yyCMocKsJNuaCh33DKmRZa1clcMlCq2+BDGkNF6la+muAgA) - the chart itself works great, but I can't get the month bars to animate from 0 to the temperatures given.

I've searched through the Ractive GitHub site and through SO, and have seen various examples given - this has given me the basis of the ractive.animate() statement I have in above link. As far as I can tell, this is not being picked up in my code - where am I going wrong? I've also checked the Ractive docs, but the content is minimal, and the examples given make it hard to work out a basic example ;-)

I think the format I have for my ractive animate statement is good, but am not sure I'm using the right values:

ractive.animate( 'high', cities.months.high, { duration: 5000, easing: 'easeInOut' } );

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `cities` variable does not exist. `ractive.animate( 'high', cities.months.high, { duration: 5000, easing: 'easeInOut' } );` would just fail.

Second, your `cities` is not in the data but it's in a property of the instance. Although Ractive [resolves unresolved data references to instance members](https://ractive.js.org/api/#resolveinstancemembers), it would be very confusing. Just store all the data in `data`.

Next, for animate to work, the values to update must have some initial value to begin with. Putting `high`s on `0` on the initial data should suffice. All we need to do now is call `ractive.set` with the new data. Whatever data Ractive can animate, it will animate.

As an added bonus, truncate the decimals off the rendered numbers. You can use the bitwise operation `|0` on the reference like `{{ cities.months[i].high|0 }}`. `Math.floor` should also work too.

[Here's an updated demo with working animation](https://ractive.js.org/playground/#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-GQVzQCBIjoAUgOALJ0bcbjd0ADKAHkAHIAEXd8q548V5BHlYuZmbYFWy9XTjtr7PLUw7Y7Xth3LNQxwnAsp25DFgDkHEwApbpnmLSc3EWFAUJoKlvG0OQ-ACIIaBAAgMHgBg9hIdkdFQNAdAvVAkBIYwqmw14wmaVowkqMIAGFLHENRdnYNQQQvNA1GEPYEzCPAWK8EBXwwTiSFbWSMV5cBxSUgBmAB2D0ZI8HlgHUl1tIANn01SyGMsJTKgEgABYqEswyqRsjS+CUhyAE4XIKdF3LsyozIABj8nwApMzT7LMiz8Csqoos8mLfPi1zIts6LgtSgz-LUzLkuC5y0ry6ykrAJSAFYtPCozyq8hzarc+r7K01LVI7FiOkQ9QyOhTJsiYRiSAcAB3EgACU4UGtBHWAFjJSiNBKlMTFFuo0xcp8VcVsxKwbDsSNNpYqjbFtFieh-P9SWUkhTA3Ta7oHR7TG3F66Bet6QXul6Hu+j7vqPF6Txes8XovE0Oy24sG0wc6Zzk9jcnsni+LEwSxJEsSJJgKSiKgsIFKUlSEfyjyKvssKSv9ZqCopyoqehu8yrppTGaglnybZ8LiwyrnKZ55nEtZgXqd5smgpIdnSc5yXpdvOqRYZwXFf55WxaFwKsqllXabVnXuoV15OpnamvBQPwkHNSpwUkNQAWsdcSDItd3Xm9LXhkGVPBqgAqEht1QMAGiQK4MEdZ2rZIV1vVUw2fHjnAY68Hq1AGnIQ7UbgJPQCOLCNGYQUo6jaPokFjJ0aQygqEhKpC+ucGj70iJAcx4AAAUhGxVnBOEOHd28u5QHuWm4BA4hW1krksFAoTQVhJGQKNY+eDAYHMSppAQR1TAaBo5CHuQJssafZ9WCb58X25RrQK4h4aUbLHBcFTHdSEYBznfH+f1+V8HpFVg32tJUNQUIJIID-scIeqwYzWxGmAq2kD47eDACgYQa4B7HCtHwG0JAqD1wYGAJBXR1DTx0HEZirloG92EGPCeJAp4zzngvJeIIMAVgwDA5g3BwSQLINAw0AAvZaUsGgAA4dKVRkMIPheokA6D0GoVglQvjSMgT0bBqDKj4JCgAUnUSgcsCj7DKLwSIAxONWD2AZgY6eKQYHcEESYyo08YA6GYKsOxxDU5rT2OwYImCNFoGAXg+u+jvDII8A0FgehLDMlZOySht59SGmyDXUOGAMySHQAYgIODtHmLmLPUQDMGiVUKR4SJ6huywncdCQJhiDRGnSWHLJOSil8RsXMUaRhkTaLCd4rkUSwz3H2Ek44KTmlqGzKuMoTADE9J0H00JeiDGaNwTo8JzwjGKNMWFMKWkRBS1sZYexQjnEkFcXUzxpzBkaCia+d8odVzjJ6KfWewhKirCoBU-+3chEiJCg0MyaiIkkLUA0MMyZEkNMmWk6ZDDZkzTWcE-JKytmD0zKgSo5pwQoAMakYeVteAIvMGJLUBidkXKBVI35ngeiLOWV8BoWlWVsoxWoKpEKwyamYK8xpqTASVAyW0tACzelgH6asuYVKlHKyoF6E5ZzHEXKuR4rxYLU4NDhTkfl7zLCfJIF8aVlTwXaqaTNEgkLbgRj5Q0tVTIYncEkDdL4XojXuv2SctxHjcUbPdZkhARgSCYjZd665eStF4IDRmYNobWXho8cU7RMag06BDWGuY+rDUhTud4c1gqhqPn5cm0RYi6U9GgUAtF08EC5k1UM6pPZi0NNLasIFYjQWmq1WGW19SWI6prjIKIORZGMslY5SqiqWLrKlRyrlDRJSTGmBgcZZBB0IuHXMsVLFx1ztkbO9FsjZWmKoLS4QOsvUNvudUkZuwxktoHRaoVApWkIGyTu1ye6j0sT9V0qhACAXaIaKoulZAg0OFWIe3NLFBHhlTGgFIwU81RMlPygRjjAUNG8l29QOBcBAA) and the code to use:

```
var updatedData = {

    "name": "Copenhagen, Denmark",
    "months": [
      { "high": 37 },
      { "high": 36 },
      { "high": 41 },
      { "high": 49 },
      { "high": 60 },
      { "high": 66 },
      { "high": 69 },
      { "high": 69 },
      { "high": 61 },
      { "high": 53 },
      { "high": 44 },
      { "high": 39 }
    ]
  }

var ractive = new Ractive({
  template: '#template',
  el: '#container',
  data: {
    monthNames: [ 'J', 'F', 'M', 'A', 'M', 'J', 'J', 'A', 'S', 'O', 'N', 'D' ],
      cities: {
        "name": "Copenhagen, Denmark",
        "months": [
          { "high": 0 },
          { "high": 0 },
          { "high": 0 },
          { "high": 0 },
          { "high": 0 },
          { "high": 0 },
          { "high": 0 },
          { "high": 0 },
          { "high": 0 },
          { "high": 0 },
          { "high": 0 },
          { "high": 0 }
        ]
      },
    scale: function ( val ) {
      return 3 * Math.abs( val );
    }
  }
});  

ractive.animate( 'cities', updatedData, { duration: 5000} );
```

Comment: Thanks a million for setting me back on the straight and narrow - I think the examples on the Ractive site make things more complicated than they need to be, which is why I got so confused! The demo works brilliantly - I love the bitwise trick too ;-)